# Connecting to PostGres in RDS with npgsql

Tags: c#, postgresql, .net-core, npgsql, rds

The following code produces 
*System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: 'No such host is known'*
on the Open() statement

```
var connection = new NpgsqlConnection("Host=dev-materialized-views-std.ckxycbarkbtw.ap-southeast-2.rds.amazonaws.com,Port=5432,Username=uname,Password=***");                                                              
connection.Open();
```

This code works:

```
var connection = new NpgsqlConnection("Host=tm-integration.ckxycbarkbtw.ap-southeast-2.rds.amazonaws.com,Port=5432,Username=uname,Password=***");
```

The only difference we can spot via the RDS console is that the working connection string points at PostGre 10.4, the failing connection string points at a 11.4 instance.

Given all else is equal (RDS network config / VPC setting) this looks like an issue in the dotnet core stack itself? We've tried this on 2.2 and 2.0, no difference.

Answer (score 1):

Sigh.

Problem was me.

Must have copied a connection string from somewhere which had "," instead of ";" as the property seperator.

I was also missing the database property.

Working conn string is:

```
Host=test2.ckxycbarkbtw.ap-southeast-2.rds.amazonaws.com;Username=unamePassword=***;Database=test2;
```

Comment: Note that if the Database parameter is omitted, Npgsql will default to the username as your database (this is standard PostgreSQL behavior). So you were in effect trying to open a database called `uname`.